# SetParent in Unity

Tags: android, unity3d, transform

Всем добрый день! Создаю приложение под android на примере https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BgPiKw8Q6Xk&list=PL0lO_mIqDDFVuqf113xXF-0JaglMUMXCV&index=14, в данный момент у меня возникла проблема, скрин которой прикрепляю ниже: [image: ошибка]

Ошибка возникает на следующем участке кода:

```
if (CubeJump.count_blocks % 1 == 0)
        {
            GameObject diamondInst = Instantiate(diamond, new Vector3(blockInst.transform.position.x, blockInst.transform.position.y + 0.5f, blockInst.transform.position.z), Quaternion.Euler(Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles)) as GameObject;
            diamondInst.transform.parent = blockInst.transform; // Ошибка здесь
        }
```

Видео-курс 2016 года, как я прочитал на других форумах, ошибка может быть связана с тем, что данный синтаксис метода parent устарел и необходимо использовать новый, но у меня никак не получается найти решение этого вопроса

Надеюсь на обратную связь

P.S. Возможно неточно объяснил, если остались вопросы пишите ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно документации, есть такой метод, как **[SetParent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html)**. Он устанавливает родителя для `transform` объекта. Возможно вам нужен он.

```
diamondInst.transform.SetParent(blockInst.transform);
```

Comment: Да, такой синтаксис не приводит к ошибке, но теперь заложенная в код функция не выполняется. Может есть другие варианты? @user:191482

Comment: @Superbarsik варианты могут быть разные, но корректный - данный. А "не выполняется" имеет тысячи вариантов значений

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, вы были правы!